# android import library dependency based on build type and flavor combinations

Tags: android, gradle, build, variant

I have some external libraries that are different versions to match all my build variants. In this example I have 4 different versions of the same library. I cannot figure out how to do this in my build.gradle file. I have two different flavors that combined with release and debug. In the example below, the commented out code works and the other code is what i'm trying to get working.

```
  android {
      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled true
          }
          debug {
              minifyEnabled false
          }
      }

      flavorDimensions "base"
      productFlavors {
          flavor1 {
              dimension "base"
              applicationIdSuffix ".flavor1"

          }
          flavor2 {
              dimension "base"
              applicationIdSuffix ".flavor2"
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      // this works but cannot specify the build type
      flavor1Implementation files('libs/mylib-release.aar')

      // this combination of buildType+Flavor is not working
      // flavor1ReleaseImplementation files('libs/mylib-flavor1-release.aar')
      // flavor1DebugImplementation   files('libs/mylib-flavor1-debug.aar')

      // this works but cannot specify the build type
      flavor2Implementation files('libs/mylib-flavor2-release.aar')

      // flavor2ReleaseImplementation files('libs/mylib-flavor2-release.aar')
      // flavor2DebugImplementation   files('libs/mylib-flavor2-debug.aar')
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code to your build.gradle file to initialize a placeholder for dependency configurations

```
// Initializes a placeholder for these dependency configurations
configurations {
    flavor1DebugImplementation {}
    flavor1ReleaseImplementation {}
    flavor2DebugImplementation {}
    flavor2ReleaseImplementation {}
}
```

Example of the full solution in the build.gradle

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "base"
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "base"
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavor1"

        }
        flavor2 {
            dimension "base"
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavor2"
        }
    }
}


// Initializes a placeholder for these dependency configurations
configurations {
    flavor1DebugImplementation {}
    flavor1ReleaseImplementation {}
    flavor2DebugImplementation {}
    flavor2ReleaseImplementation {}
}


dependencies {
    //flavor1Implementation files('libs/mylib-release.aar')

    flavor1ReleaseImplementation files('libs/mylib-flavor1-release.aar')
    flavor1DebugImplementation   files('libs/mylib-flavor1-debug.aar')

    //flavor2Implementation files('libs/mylib-flavor2-release.aar')
    
    flavor2ReleaseImplementation files('libs/mylib-flavor2-release.aar')
    flavor2DebugImplementation   files('libs/mylib-flavor2-debug.aar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This way will work in multi-module projects**

create a build gradle file (for example flavor_config.gradle) and define your config in it like this

```
android {
    flavorDimensions 'resource_type'
    productFlavors {
        create("flavor1") {
            dimension 'resource_type'
            versionName "$app_version_name - flavor1"
        }
        create("flavor2") {
            dimension 'resource_type'
            versionName "$app_version_name - flavor2"
        }
    }
}
```

and apply this gradle file for every module that you want for example app module or a feature module like this:

```
apply from: rootProject.file("flavor_config.gradle")
```

after sync project you can access to specific of implementation of each flavor like this:

```
flavor1Implementation("flavor1Library")
flavor2Implementation("flavor2Library")
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, [edit] the answer and tailor the post to the question.